# WP_REST_Request::get_json_params() Parsing null as Zero

Tags: rest-api

**Why do I get `0` when WP_REST_Request::get_json_params() parses a JSON body value of null?**

I have a method which is responsible for turning a `WP_REST_Request` into another format which is acceptable for my business logic.

```php
function prepare_item_for_database(WP_REST_Request $request): array
{
    $payload = $request->get_json_params();
    // ... validation
    return $payload;
}
```

When I have a request which includes `null` values, the `WP_REST_Request::get_json_params()` function creates PHP `0`, instead of `null`. I get the following.

**Why do I get `0` in the PHP array, instead of `null`?**

HTTP POST Body

```json
{
    "name": "s",
    "feature_id": null,
    "note_id": null
}
```

PHP Parsed Value

```php
// What I get
Array
(
    [name] => s
    [feature_id] => 0
    [note_id] => 0
)

// What I expect
Array
(
    [name] => s
    [feature_id] => null
    [note_id] => null
)
```

The schema for the endpoint is like the following

```php
[
    'properties' => [
        'name'  => [
            'type' => 'string'
        ],
        'feature_id' => [
            'type' => 'integer'
        ],
        'note_id' => [
            'type' => 'integer'
        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Which Wordpress version are you running? Testing this locally I get the expected value of null so I am think either it has to do with the version you are currently running or perhaps there is a filter involved? Can you show the schema for the rest endpoint?

Comment: Wordpress 6.0.2 & PHP 7.4.1. Schema does have "type": "integer" for these properties.

Comment: And.......changing the schema to `'type' => ['integer', 'null'],` causes null to be parsed. So it was the schema.

Comment: Well then that is the reason, if you are using integer the params will be converted to integers and if you do `intval(null)` you will get 0.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to how you declare the parameter types for the endpoint. If you use `integer` then the parameters will be converted to integers, so in cases where a null value is being used you will get 0. The solution is to add support for both `integer` and `null` e.g.

```
'type' => ['integer', 'null'],
```